# Hibernate is not able to load a JAR file if my directory name contains space!

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have an application that is based on Swing, Spring 2.5.2, Hibernate 3.3.1.

If my application is run from a directory that contains a space character, for example `D:\hudson\jobs\FooBar - Fast Build`, then I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-persistence.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/D:/hudson/jobs/FooBar%20-%20Fast%20Build/workspace/commons/target/classes/
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:463)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/D:/hudson/jobs/FooBar%20-%20Fast%20Build/workspace/commons/target/classes/
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:635)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:350)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\hudson\jobs\FooBar%20-%20Fast%20Build\workspace\commons\target\classes (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.jboss.util.file.JarArchiveBrowser.<init>(JarArchiveBrowser.java:74)
    at org.jboss.util.file.FileProtocolArchiveBrowserFactory.create(FileProtocolArchiveBrowserFactory.java:48)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\hudson\jobs\FooBar%20-%20Fast%20Build\workspace\commons\target\classes (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:133)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:97)
    at org.jboss.util.file.JarArchiveBrowser.<init>(JarArchiveBrowser.java:69)
    ... 49 more
```

*(note that in this case, the error occurs during a unit test launched by a Hudson job)*

As you can see, each space character is replaced by a `%20` in the URL, which may be the source of the problem...

Do you have any idea why this happens, and how to solve it (of course, renamming the whole path of my application will solve the problem, but it is not the kind of answer that I am looking for ;) ) ?

ps: I don't know if it can help you, but the bean `entityManagerFactory` is created in the `spring-persistence.xml` file with the following definition:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="oraclePersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

(the properties are defined in another place of the spring definition, or in a `persistence.xml` file)

---

The error is thrown when I run the following code in my application:

```
applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/my-spring-config.xml");
```

`my-spring-config` is located in the `src/main/resources` directory of my application.
I've also tested with a `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` instead, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: The paths in the RuntimeException and FileNotFoundException are different.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it's just a problem of copy-paste, the "real" paths are exactly identical... (edited now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this is due to a bug in the version of `hibernate-entitymanager` I was using (`3.3.1.ga`).

By replacing this version with the latest one (`3.4.0.GA`), the problem does not occur anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The %20 is the normal way to URL-encode spaces.

Sounds like you are treating an URL like a plain filename, which is incorrect.  How is this information passed down to Ejb3Configuration?

Comment: The problem is that I do not give any URL to the Ejb3Configuration, nor to any Hibernate file. It seems to be a problem in the Hibernate initialization...

Comment: Well, in that case, run your ant task inside Eclipse in debug mode and wait for the exception to be caught by the debugger.  Then you can backtrack and see where the location comes from.

Comment: I've edited my post to show how the spring configuration is loaded. I really don't know what I can do now to solve my problem...